# Ansible: install package only if is the newest version

Tags: regex, ansible

**Introduction:** The objetive is to install and configure a package into a on premise server (without internet connection).

I already achieved a task to install using a `.deb` file and the [apt module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html), and also configure the service using the [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html) module to edit the package configuration files.

**The problem:** if the server already has an old version!

I'm able to get the current version installed using the command:

```sh
dpkg-query -f '${Version}' -W packageName`
```

and I also developed [an regex](https://regex101.com/r/m0fWfc/1/) to get the number to compare.

But now I'm stuck! =/

**Question**:
How can I use the regex to compare the current version number with the version number to be installed?

I already read the [filter documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html), but it did not rang any bells. >.<

Uninstall and install is also an option but it doesn't seems the right one.

Comment: Have you simply tried to install the new .deb package ? (proceding exactly like when it is not present). It should work out of the box from what I remember and not touch anything if the version is the same, exactly as if using a name (I might have a bad memory though....). Meanwhile, regarding versions, you have checked filters whereas you actually want to look for a [test](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#comparing-versions)

Comment: @Zeitounator, the [test](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#comparing-versions) fulfilled the task of version comparison, thanks! Installing the .deb on top of an older version reinstalled and erased all the configuration. So, using a register and applying all the configuration when installation changes occours worked well. Installing on top of a same version, does not change anything indeed! Is a viable solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

I cannot post a comment due to <50 rep at this point so I'll try to elaborate as much as I can. I hope this does answer your question, please comment if not.

If the issue is with installing when an older version is already installed, you can use the "only_upgrade" option of the apt module:

```
shell: ansible-doc apt
- only_upgrade
        Only upgrade a package if it is already installed.
        [Default: no]
        type: bool
        version_added: 2.1
```

Then, when adding a `register` var to this action, you'll know if the packages was indeed upgraded, and assuming you need to push new config files due to version change, you have what you need.
The flow would be:

```
- name: Attempt upgrade first
   apt: 
     deb: path/to/file.deb
   only_upgrade: True
   register: was_upgraded

- name: Install the package on a server that never had it
  apt:
    deb: path/to/file.deb
  when: was_upgraded.false
```

Comment: I took a time to answer, I was doing several tests in my work environment.

Comment: So, for the case that I was working on, using apt without `only_upgrade` is easier due to the fact that it only changes the files if the package is not installed or with a lower version, as @Zeitounator mentioned. It covered all the current needs.

If requires a more sofisticated control, `only_update`is definitly the best option. Thanks!